# is C++ raw pointer used to initialise a shared pointer invalidated when the shared pointer goes out of scope?

Tags: c++

I'd expect the following code to give rise to undefined behaviour on the line `delete mp;`. Is that correct?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void func(int* p)
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> sp {p};
    *sp = 19;
    
    std::cout << "p : " << p << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*p : " << *p << std::endl;
    std::cout << "&(*p) : " << &(*p) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "&p : " << &p << std::endl << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "sp : " << sp << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*sp : " << *sp << std::endl;
    std::cout << "&(*sp) : " << &(*p) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "&sp : " << &sp << std::endl << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "sp.get() : " << sp.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*sp.get() : " << *sp.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "&(*sp.get()) : " << &(*sp.get()) << std::endl;
    int* up {sp.get()};
    std::cout << "&up : " << &up << std::endl << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int* mp = new int (10);
    
    func(mp);
    
    std::cout << "mp : " << mp << std::endl;
    std::cout << "*mp : " << *mp << std::endl;
    std::cout << "&(*mp) : " << &(*mp) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "&mp : " << &mp << std::endl;
    
    delete mp;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output from C++ Shell:

```
p : 0x37f8430;  *p : 19;  &(*p) : 0x37f8430;  &p : 0x7c54bc73b598

sp : 0x37f8430;  *sp : 19;  &(*sp) : 0x37f8430;  &sp : 0x7c54bc73b5b0

sp.get() : 0x37f8430;  *sp.get() : 19;  &(*sp.get()) : 0x37f8430;  &up : 0x7c54bc73b5a8

mp : 0x37f8430;  *mp : 0;  &(*mp) : 0x37f8430;  &mp : 0x7c54bc73b5e8
```

Comment: How exactly did you expect this *undefined* behavior to behave?

Comment: Undefined behavior is *undefined*. It doesn't mean "crash"; it could still "work" by some measure.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas  Yes, understood - just checking that it would be 'undefined'.

Comment: Yes, double free is undefined behavior. Why do you even want to use a shared_ptr in this case?

Comment: You get a dangling pointer.  Dereferencing or deleting such a pointer is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @idmean  I wouldn't. A colleague suggested that the standard 'guarantees' that the raw pointer would not be invalidated in this scenario. I was skeptical...